# Where Does PCB of a process lies inside the main memory

Tags: process, operating-system, process-management

Since Process in main memory is stored in the form of stack, heap, data section and static data section. Where does the PCB lies in here? Or is it stored independent from this?

Is it stored on the bottom of the stack of the process or is it independent of the memory representation of process

Comment: Probably in swappable kernel section, as are the Thread Control Blocks and stacks linked to it.

Answer (score 2):

PCB (Process Control Blocks) which contains all the info about a process are usually stored in a specially reserved memory as part of the kernel space.

The kernel space, part of logical space in RAM, is the core of an Operating System which has full access to the underlying hardware.

[image]